# Can the histogram size in the legend of a tmap be adjusted?

Tags: r, legend, histogram

Really enjoying tmap, and very happy to see the inclusion of histograms. Can that hist object be modified in any way? See below how the natural histogram object is somewhat squished.

[image]

```
this_name = "Cumberland"
this_county = nc_cr[nc_cr$NAME == this_name,]
tm_shape(this_county) +
  tm_fill("grey")+
  tm_shape(this_county) +
  tm_borders("black") + 
  tm_shape(all_exposures_cr[this_county,], 
           size=2)+ #spectral or set1 RdYlGn
  tm_dots(col="type", palette="Spectral", legend.hist=T, title="Environmental Exposure Type", scale=1.2,size=.1)+
  #tm_markers(col="type", legend.hist=T, title="Environmental Exposure Type", scale=1.2,size=.1)+
  tm_layout(frame = F, inner.margins = 0, outer.margins = 0, asp = 0, legend.text.size = 1)+
  tm_legend(legend.outside=T, legend.outside.position="right")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The width can be adjusted using "legend.hist.width" under the tm_layout function in tmap. You might want to try tm_layout(legend.hist.width = .5) or something like that. Hope this helps.